# How to count the number of unique values in column B associated with each value in column A?

Tags: postgresql

My Data resembles something like this

```
Column A    Column B
101             1001
101             1002
101             1003
101             1004
102             1001
102             1005
102             1006
101             1001
102             1001
```

Expected Output is like this

```
column_a      unique_column_b_vals
101                  4
102                  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that COUNT function supports a distinct argument

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-count-function/

```
select column_a , count(distinct column_b)
from f1 
group by column_a
```